# SSMS 2014 Service provider must implement IVsDebugger interface

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm getting the following errors when launching Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

> The 'VsDebugPresentationPackage, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' package did not load correctly.
>
> The 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by running the application together with the /log parameter on the command line, and then examining the file 'C:\Users\Leah\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AppEnv\10.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

I have checked the ActivityLog.xml and have found the following errors:

```
<entry>
    <record>1063</record>
    <time>2016/09/09 10:51:43.711</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91]</description>
    <guid>{04401FF3-8B0F-4D2D-85EB-2A3542867A8B}</guid>
    <hr>80070057 - E_INVALIDARG</hr>
    <errorinfo>Service provider must implement IVsDebugger interface</errorinfo>
</entry>
<entry>
    <record>1064</record>
    <time>2016/09/09 10:51:43.714</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91]</description>
    <guid>{04401FF3-8B0F-4D2D-85EB-2A3542867A8B}</guid>
    <hr>80070057 - E_INVALIDARG</hr>
    <errorinfo>Service provider must implement IVsDebugger interface</errorinfo>
</entry>
```

This message has started appearing today after my PC black screened during windows updates. After several more black screens and further forced restarts, windows restored to a previous version and booted successfully. I have tried doing a fresh install of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 but it hasn't changed the outcome.

This is the update that caused the black screens: Feature update to Windows 10, version 1607

Any help welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it wasn't related to the update. My machine.config wasn't correct as I had put the connection string above config section in the machine.config.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config